# ubuntu phonegap run android error 1

Tags: android, shell, cordova, ubuntu

I'm trying to run the Hello-World app of Phonegap on Ubuntu 16.

*"/my-app# phonegap --verbose run android"*

But no matter what it always takes very long and finishes with an error:

*"Running adb shell command "getprop dev.bootcomplete" on target emulator-5584..."*

*"Running command: adb -s emulator-5584 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete"*

*"Command finished with **error code 1: adb -s,emulator-5584,shell,getprop,dev.bootcomplete**"*

I've creating different avds and running everything as root user but no change.

Any suggestion what this "error code 1" means would be highly appreciated - I could only find other error codes with the search.

Comment: I just fixed it. When running "cordova run android" instead it shows that is looks for the emulator in a wrong place. So i just copied the emulator there and fixed the ini-File. Thanks for the tipps Swr7der by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `adb kill-server` and restart doing all the process again.

**EDIT:**
Try starting emulator with ubuntu cmd:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x8stdc++.so.6' ~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_21
```

where `Nexus_5X_API_21` is your emulator name

`~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator` is your path where emulator is stored

Do this after `adb kill-server`, then on another cmd tab, try running

```
phonegap emulate android --verbose
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I just tried but unfortunately still the same.

Comment: Your emulator is working properly? And this command should be used by closing the emulator , in ubuntu cmd, you did the same?

Comment: Yes I can start the emulator in Ubuntu bash. It loads normally. But when I start "phonegap run android" the emulator never loads.

Comment: However i noticed it tries to load "emulator-5584" but in "android avd" it only has "emulator-5554"?

Comment: Updated, can you check according to steps and tell me the result?

Comment: ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x8stdc++.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
adb_server_notify: Failed to establish connection to ADB server
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554

Comment: and phonegap run android still tries to load emulator-5584

Comment: I have experienced that if you manually start the AVD before issuing the run command then you do not get this error. Also I found that running an older version of android solves this issue. I do not know exactly how this happens

Comment: If you have android studio then you can launch emulator from that and use run command in ubuntu cmd to run phonegap app. It automatically detects. However, phonegap build android makes the apk of the app. Try if you are able to build the apk

Comment: I only have the commandline tools since I had even more errors trying to install the "android studio"

Comment: You have just one option: Try killing adb server then restarting emulator. However I found a way to direct phonegap to run on particular emulator:
phonegap emulate --target=emulator-5554 android